# Intended location for personal code

Tags: filesystem, home-directory

For my entire Ubuntu life I've put code directories, usually git repos, in `~/Documents`. According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HomeFolder, all personal files can go here. Ostensibly however, `~/Documents` is for documents, and code is not really the same as documents. So what was intended by Ubuntu for code storage (can't be `/usr/local/src`)?  Unspecified? A new directory like `~/projects`? (And why were the directories all capitalized anyway?)

Comment: You can define wherever you want and just redefine the `PATH` in your `.profile` and `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put code in any directory you like.

I keep my bash scripts in `/home/<yourname>/bin/`.

The advantage is that directory is in PATH, thus you run the bash code from any directory.